# Фильтрация по списку из csv

Tags: powershell

Доброго времени суток,

У меня есть скрипт который получает ip адреса объектов инфраструктуры (допустим виртуальных машин). И есть Csv со списком ip адресов. Как мне отфильтровать вывод скрипта по списку ip из csv.
Я пробовал Where {$_ -in "ip"} и switch, но понял как добавить в них список из csv.
Заведомо благодарен.

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так:

```
$ipList = (import-csv -Path c:\folderPath\ip.csv).ip #Загруаем ip из csv файла. Допустим столбец будет называться "ip"

[array] $ipServers # Список ip из вашего скрипта

foreach ($ip in $ipServers){   # Перебираем ip из скрипта в цикле
    foreach ($ipCSV in $ipList){ # Внутри перебираем список ip из CSV, да простят меня истинные программисты
        if ($ip -like $ipCSV){
            Write-Host $ip #Если совподают выполняем блок команд
            break
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[System.Net.IPAddress[]]$ipList = @("10.0.0.1", "10.0.0.2", "10.0.0.3", "10.0.0.4", "10.0.0.5")
[System.Net.IPAddress[]]$ipServers = @("10.0.0.4", "10.0.0.5", "10.0.0.6", "10.0.0.7", "10.0.0.8")
[System.Linq.Enumerable]::Intersect($ipList, $ipServers)
```

Использую метод Intersect библиотеки Linq можно получить пересечение двух множеств.